# Compose on source with multiple columns?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Goal: Read a Excel file, remove duplicates and write output to Dataverse.

I'm stuck at removing duplicates. Seems Logicapps doesn't really have any basic logic for this and instead one needs to resort to work-arounds.

I'm trying to use compose as I found that as that appeared as a solution on multiple sources. If I add data from a single column from my Excel file to an array and use compose on that, it works. But it doesn't work on an array with multiple columns. I used `union(variables('myArray'),variables('myArray'))`.

I also tried using Select to create a collection and apply Compose to that as per https://www.codit.eu/blog/working-with-collections-in-logic-apps/?country_sel=be but that did not work either.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data inside `variables('myArray')` and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

According to syntax of union expression:

```
union(collection1,collection2,collection3...)
```

One of the workaround that we can try is **Initialising Array** every column to array and then using **compose** connector on it.

Here is an example that I worked on

[image]

[image]

In **compose** I'm using this

```
union(variables('NameArray'),variables('AgeArray'),variables('IdArray'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most efficient method I’ve seen to find & remove duplicates in Logic Apps / Power Automate:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Find-and-Remove-Duplicates/td-p/2191403